# Possible to make one Hello World exe work in all versions of .NET? (2.0 and 4.5)

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, .net-2.0, .net-4.5

Is it possible to have a single .NET exe operate on all versions of .NET from 2.0 through 4.5 without having separate binaries?

Assume all I need to do is `Console.Writeline("Hello world");`

Comment: Compile it for 2.0, and it will also work on 3.0 and 4.0 and 4.5, etc.. The target framework is a minimal requirement, doesn't need an exact match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, just make sure to target the framework .Net 2.0.

You may see: [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx)

> The .NET Framework 4.5 is **backward-compatible** with applications
>   that were built with the .NET Framework versions 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5,
>   and 4. In other words, applications and components built with previous
>   versions of the .NET Framework will work on the .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 2):

You can target .NET 2.0, which will also run on .NET 4.0 because of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Crate Application any IDE with .Net Framework 2.0. So that you can able to run in any Framework above 2.0. .Net Framework supports Backward Compatibility.